# How to use a custom post type archive as front page in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to use a custom post type archive as a site's front page, so that

```
 http://the_site.com/
```

is a custom post type archive displayed according to my `archive-{post-type}.php` file.

Ideally I would like to alter the query using `is_front_page()` in my `functions.php` file. I tried the following, with a page called "Home" as my front page:

```
 add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts');
 function my_get_posts($query){
     global $wp_the_query;
     if(is_front_page()&&$wp_the_query===$query){
        $query->set('post_type','album');
        $query->set('posts_per_page',-1);
     }
     return $query;
 }
```

but the front page is returning the content of "Home" and seems to be ignoring the custom query.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way, in general, of going about this?

*Note: I did post this in [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30851/how-to-use-a-custom-post-type-archive-as-front-page) but that community is comparatively tiny.*

Comment: I don't know what a custom post type archive is, but you might try this: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-post-types-archive-page-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks, but I have no problem creating a custom post type archive (the ability to archive custom post types is now native in WP, and no longer requires `query-posts`). My issue is altering the query BEFORE the template is called.

Comment: What's the difference between your home page template (front-page.php) and your custom post type archive (archive-post-type.php)?

Comment: Barely any. They both contain a loop with some very basic formatting. However, if my function were working, the content would not be that of the "Home" page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Posting the final solution as an answer (Isaac placed it as a comment) just for anyone still looking.

Isaac was on the right track with adding a filter via `functions.php`. What he did wrong was call `is_front_page()`, which doesn't work yet because we're in `pre_get_posts` and the query hasn't been executed yet.

We do have the current page ID however. So we can still solve this, by looking into the WordPress option register for an option called `page_on_front`, which returns the ID of the page the user set as frontpage.

(For an overview of all WordPress options, just visit `<yourwordpressinstallation>/wp-admin/options.php` in your browser.)

Which makes for the following solution [as suggested by Ijaas](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30851/how-to-use-a-custom-post-type-archive-as-front-page/30854#30854):

```
add_action("pre_get_posts", "custom_front_page");
function custom_front_page($wp_query) {
    // Compare queried page ID to front page ID.
    if(!is_admin() && $wp_query->get("page_id") == get_option("page_on_front")) {

        // Set custom parameters (values based on Isaacs question).
        $wp_query->set("post_type", "album");
        $wp_query->set("posts_per_page", -1);

        // WP_Query shouldn't actually fetch the page in our case.
        $wp_query->set("page_id", "");

    }
}
```

You might have to alter a few conditional tags to make sure all plugins still work, depending on how heavily the query gets altered.

Hope this helps someone.

**Update:** as noted [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20948532/1854499), add `!is_admin()` to the `if`-statement to make sure the function only runs on the frontend. If you only want this action to run for the initial query, you could also add the main query check `$wp_query->is_main_query()`.

Answer (score 3):

In response to Robberts solution:

> answered May 6 '13 at 12:04

adding `&& !isAdmin()` to the if function other wise it replaces the post type query for all admin pages as well.
Just in case anyone has issues with this.

edit:
also adding `&& $wp_query->is_main_query()` to the if statement stops it affecting widgets and the menu

so total code I have

`if($wp_query->get("page_id") == get_option("page_on_front") && !isAdmin() && $wp_query->is_main_query()) {}`

Comment: Please write this as a comment next time, so I get a notification allowing me to update my comment. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Didn't have a high enough reputation score to comment sorry!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get that query to work, you're going to have to add that code to a page template, create a page, set your template as the template for the page you just created, and then set that page as the home page in Settings => Reading in the admin area.

By the way, the `is_front_page()` function only returns true if you're on a page that's been set as the home page from the admin menu.

The other option would be to modify `index.php`, but if you did that, `is_front_page()` would always return false. In that case, you'd want to use `is_home()` instead.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Philip, that isn't true. You can alter queries from `functions.php`, in fact it is the preferred method for [a number of reasons](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Caveats). As I mentioned in the question, I _do_ have "Home" set as the front page via the admin menu, and it presently does indeed call `front-page.php` for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

Isaac, you are correct, I didn't thoroughly read your question and I made the assumption that you were looking to do this the "easy" way.

Anyway, I put your code on my test site and, indeed, it didn't work. I looked at my SQL log and it turns out that your code produces this in the query `wp_posts.post_status = 'private'`.

So, I tried adding the line `$query->set('post_status', 'public');` to your function, and it worked just fine.

In summary, try this:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts');
function my_get_posts($query){
    global $wp_the_query;
    if(is_front_page()&&$wp_the_query===$query){
        $query->set('post_type','album');
        $query->set('posts_per_page',-1);
        $query->set('post_status', 'public');
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: That's interesting, however adding that line for me produces a 404. What ended up working was the answer [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30851/how-to-use-a-custom-post-type-archive-as-front-page/30854#30854) although I have no idea what it's doing exactly.